# Reading capacitor voltage over ESP8266 A0 pin

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to read capacitor voltage over ESP8266 A0 pin. Positive capacitor output is always conected to A0. Negative is connected to ESP8266 via a BC547 transistor to prevent capacitor discharge.
Transistor acts as a switch - it connects capacitor negative to ESP GND for voltage reading only when I send a high signal to the base of this NPN transistor. Voltage reading over A0 works fine, but I get a reading even when the transistor is off. What could be the issue ?[image]

Comment: As drawn, the capacitor is always connected to GND and it is the ESP's ground pin that's being switched...

Comment: Yes, I'm switching ESP GND to capacitor negative via transistor. I want to prevent A0 discharging capacitor when it is not performing reading. Is this correct way to perform this ?

Comment: Draw the rest of the circuit. Where does "PIR OUT 3.3V" come from and where is it's ground connected?

Comment: PIR 3.3v is pir sensor output. I'm using capacitor to store PIR value (if PIR was high). Pir GND is connected to capacitor negative.

Comment: This won't work for various reasons, why not simply use a input that can trigger a interrupt if you don't want to miss an event ?

Comment: I considered using interrupts, but I  need to conserve energy.  PIR triggers will keep ESP wake too often. This way I can store PIR HIGH value in capacitor and later check capacitor voltage (I wake ESP each hour). If it is>2 volt I will consider that PIR was triggered. ESP reads capacitor coltage over A0 and during this 1 minute period it will discharge if it was high.

Comment: If you only need to know if the PIR was triggered during the hour the ESP sleeps (and not how many times it was triggered) you could use a interrupt to wake up on PIR trigger, and then disable the wake-up on PIR trigger before going to sleep again. So it'll only wake up once on the first trigger...

Comment: Thank you, that is a great idea ! What module do you suggest for this purpose ? ESP-12F ? I considered using this arragement [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPd362tRx5o)

Answer (score 0):

Very low current analog 1 bit memory

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2ocVh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can isolate the capacitor using a MOSFT as switch. If you want to check the capacitor voltage, you activate the MCU output *WANT_READ* and immediately take an ADC measurement. This way there is no current consumption via R1 during sleep mode.

The voltage at *MCU_ADC* can be lower than the capacitor voltage because it will not rise above VCC - Vthr (the threshold voltage of the MOSFET). But since the purpose of this circuit is only a kind of event memory, this should not be important as long as a FET with low threshold is used.

Finally the capacitor fully discharges via R1 and a new cycle can start after *WANT_READ* is low again.

This circuit is not free from leakage currents but will hold the information for some hours.

Some MCUs have a very high dc input resistance at their ADC inputs (e.g. 100 Mohm ATmega88-328 series) and the circuit would not be needed at all for 1 hour info hold time.

Edit:
Alternative solution with BJT

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fphNuF.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this schematic. Is it possible to use 3.3v logic level mosfet like IRLZ44N since I can obtain BSS138 only in SMD version ? Or perhaps an opto coupler ?

Comment: @Marc IRLZ44N is not an option, but an opto coupler is a good idea. I just don't know the typical leakage current of them. An NPN with 50 kohm base resistor may also work.

Comment: could you help me with schematic using PC817 optocoupler ?  I tried to connect A0 pin to PIN4 (colector) of opto and  pin 4 (emiter) to output of capacitor. But I get consant A0 reading despite of opto state (I'm controling opto using digital output).  PIR and ESP8266 are connected to same battery. Could this be the issue ?

Comment: Its just the other way round: collector to the capacitor, emitter to R1, because the voltage at C1 is more positive (in case of an event)

Comment: The opto coupler needs 18µs time to conduct, so you have to wait that before reading the ADC (delayMicoseconds)

Comment: The circuit is working great now using optocoupler. However, capacitor discharge rate is quite high. 470uF capacitor discharges in about 20 minutes to almost 0 volt and I need a hold time of one hour. What could be the reason ? Maybe diode is draining the capacitor ?

Comment: It could be the capacitor itself, many are leaky, Tanatalum caps are good in this discipline. Test the cap connected to nothing, charge up, leave alone and measure after time. I like diode BAV199 for ver low reverse current, but there are others.

Comment: I've tested the cap alone, it is holding the charge fo hours. I'm trying to test the current leak with ampmeter. I've connected it in series between capacitor positive and diode but I only get a reading greater than zero when the ESP is performing voltage reading (I've tryed all scales-uA,mA). Am I performing this test correctly ?